# RSA encryption in Objective-C (Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, encryption, rsa

I'm hacking around on stuff that requires RSA encryption and I've got some code which looks like this:

```
- (NSData *)RSAEncryptData:(NSData *)data {

    NSMutableData * encrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:256];

    RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa->n = BN_bin2bn(modulus.bytes, modulus.length, NULL);
    rsa->e = BN_bin2bn(exponent.bytes, exponent.length, NULL);

    RSA_public_encrypt(data.length, data.bytes, encrypted.mutableBytes, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    return encrypted;

}
```

Where modulus and exponent are `NSData` objects.

This works just fine, apart from all the RSA methods make the compiler whine at me about how they're deprecated on Mac OS 10.7.

Is there a more modern way I should be doing this? I've been Googling for a few hours and could only find iOS stuff which isn't available on the Mac (`SecKeyEncrypt`, etc).

To be absolutely clear, I'm not looking for an iOS solution, I'm looking for a Mac OS one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the Next-Generation Cryptographic Services presentation at WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), OpenSSL is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.7 and later, as versioning for the OpenSSL libraries is horrific.

That being said, there's currently no direct replacement for the RSA functions in OpenSSL. Yet. You can probably continue using them for now; you'll just have to live with the warnings. Alternatively, you can take the advice given by Jon Callas in that presentation and bundle your own copy of libcrypto for RSA.

Comment: Well my base64 methods have shrunk since reading that article, so that's a positive :) It's a shame there's no Security framework alternative for RSA, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already reviewed [this](https://github.com/andrewtj/cutkey/issues/2)? It seems the exact problem your asking, however, this questions seems to be solved.

Comment: At any rate, my vision on compilers is: Don't whine while not presenting an alternative solution ;)

Comment: Indeed, not exactly what I'm looking for (a non-openssl solution would be nice), but it does reinforce that it's okay to use older libs to shut the compiler up.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out if it helps

https://github.com/skomik/RSAUtility